# how to work out a total % for 2 components worth 60% and 40%

Tags: percentages, ratio

Trying to work out the overall mark for a module with 2 components eg.
component A is worth 40 % of the total and is awarded 55 out of 100
component B is worth 60 % of the total and is awarded 52 out of 100
What is the overall mark and how is it worked out?
I am an art teacher!hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the overall mark  will be in percentage points, on the scale $0-100$. The student got 
$$
\frac{55}{100} \cdot 40 = 22 \text{ points}
$$
for component A, and 
$$
\frac{52}{100} \cdot 60 = 31.2 \text{ points}
$$
for component B. Their total is  $22+31.2 = 53.2$ (out of $100$).